# todo list and memory usage applet on desktop?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

I would like to have information on my desktop in a very simple text mod or memory usage and processor activity and daily to do lists.

I was wondering what kind of applications are available on Ubuntu for that?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[todo.txt](http://ginatrapani.github.com/todo.txt-cli/) with Conky is my favorite setup. Command line todo list hotness, displayed on your desktop!

Comment: thanks; any links or tutorials on setting that up?

Comment: Why yes, actually. Here is the link for using it with conky:
http://wiki.github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/linux-with-conky

Here is the general startup tips link for using todo.txt:
http://wiki.github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/quick-start-guide